# Showing some transformation is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, transformation

> Let $T: P_3(\mathbb{R}) \to P_3(\mathbb{R})$ be an operation defined by
>   $$T(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3) = a + dx + (a+d)x^2  +(b-c)x^3$$
>   Show that $T$ is linear

What I have done so far is look at it like this(since such transformations are homomorphic):

$$T(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3) = aT(1) + bT(x) + cT(x^2) + dT(x^3)$$

Now it would seem that the transformation does nothing, and rather the coefficients have been rearranged.

$\left( \begin{align} a\\b\\c\\d \end{align} \right)$ = $ a\left( \begin{align} 1\\-1\\0\\-1 \end{align} \right)$

Does this show that $T$ is linear? Or what am I meant to do?

Comment: I do not understand what you have done... :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you have done but then this is what you are supposed to do :

**You have to show that $T(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3)=aT(1)+bT(x)+cT(x^2)+dT(x^3)$**

It is given that $$T(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3) = a + dx + (a+d)x^2  +(b-c)x^3$$

So, we have :

- $T(1)=T(1+0\cdot x+0 \cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3)=1+0\cdot x+(1+0)x^2+(0-0)x^3=1+x^2$

So, $T(1)=1+x^2$

- $T(x)=T(0+1\cdot x+0 \cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3)=0+0\cdot x+(0+0)x^2+(1-0)x^3=x^3$

So,$T(x)=x^3$

- $T(x^2)=T(0+0\cdot x+1 \cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3)=0+0\cdot x+(0+0)x^2+(0-1)x^3=-x^3$

So, $T(x^2)=-x^3$

- $T(x^3)=T(0+0\cdot x+0 \cdot x^2+1\cdot x^3)=0+1\cdot x+(0+1)x^2+(0-0)x^3=x+x^2$

So, $T(x^3)=x+x^2$

Now, can you show that :

$$T(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3)=aT(1)+bT(x)+cT(x^2)+dT(x^3)$$

P.S : I have computed only $T(1)$ before and **user142198** understood this and accepted this answer. But then another user **Exam in 5 days** was having issues in computing $T(x),T(x^2),T(x^3)$ and so i have computed that Only for him..

Comment: $T(1)=1, T(x)=\frac{dx}b, T(x^2)=\frac{(a+d)x^2}c,T(x^3)=\frac{(b-c)x^3}d$?

Is that what you are getting at?(obviously that dx isn't derivative w.r.t x)

Comment: why would you get $\frac{dx}{b}$ for $T(x)$??? i do not understand this

Comment: Because $bT(x)$ becomes $dx$, which means the expression $bT(x)=b*\frac{dx}{b} = dx$ which is what we want to end with right?

Comment: You have totally misunderstood what i have said...

Comment: I am doing a similar problem, and I don't understand what is being done here. Can you give me $T(x)$ above so I have something to compare $T(1)$ with?

Comment: @Examin5days : I do not understand what your problem is... :O

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I just meant can you expand on your advice to user142198 above by giving $T(x)$ so I can compare it with $T(1)$, sorry for not being more specific the first time

Comment: @Exam: To get $T(x)$ you need the argument $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$ to be equal to $x$. What values of $a,b,c,d$ will do this?

Comment: @EricStucky $(a,b,c,d) = (0,1,0,0)$, but won't doing this with $T(1),T(x),T(x^2),T(x^3)$ just give me a diagonal matrix?(unless I am doing stuff like $(0,0,\frac1x,0$)

Comment: @Exam: It will not. Even $T(x)$ finds a nonzero entry which lies off the diagonal, and in fact the only nonzero entry on the diagonal is in the 1,1 position. Maybe we are interpreting things differently: what gave you the impression that it would be diagonal? [And yes, the values for $a,b,c,d$ should be constants, so no fancy $x$ business.]

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Okay I understand all of it except for $T(1)$, why isn't $T(1)= 1 + x^2$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yeah $T(1)=1+x^2$ that was what was confusing me(since it was all you put up initially). Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Examin5days : I have edited it...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably mixing to ideas - checking the definitions of linearity of $T$ and writing down (if $T$ is linear) the corresponding $4 \times 4$ matrix w.r.t. $\mathbb{R}$-basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. This should lead to

$ T=\left( \begin{align} 1 && 0 && 0 && 0\\0 && 0 && 0 && 1\\1 && 0 && 0 && 1\\0 && 1 && -1 && 0 \\\end{align} \right)$

Comment: While this is a perfectly good answer to anyone who understands the subject; I'm not sure it's very useful to the OP. Even the fact that one can write down an arbitrary linear transformation as a matrix is not particularly trivial (definitely not transparent unless you're already familiar with the result). And if you do think that the OP is mixing up two ideas, I don't think introducing a third is usually the best way to go about things. [You'll notice the OP does not use the word matrix at all.]

Comment: I'm not saying that an answer necessarily needs to help the OP, but it should be useful to someone. I admit this could be my fault, but I'm not seeing the audience here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p,p'\in P_3(\mathbb{R})$ and let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $$p=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$$ and $$p=a'+b'x+c'x^2+d'x^3.$$

It is your job to show that $T(p+p')=T(p)+T(p')$ and $T(\alpha p)=\alpha T(p)$.

Answer (score -1):

Given

$$
T\Big( a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3 \Big) = a + dx + ( a + d ) x^2 + ( b - c ) x^3
$$

You need to show that $T$ is linear, thus

$$
T\Big( a P_1 + b P_2 \Big) = a T\Big( P_1 \Big) + b T\Big( P_2 \Big),
$$

where

$$
P_k = a_k + b_k x + c_k x^2 + d_k x^3.
$$

and it is clear that $T$ is linear.

---

Note that

$$
T( 1 - x - x^3) = 1 - x - x^3
$$

and

$$
T( x + x^2 ) = 0
$$

Comment: It sure does look like you wrote "You need to show that $T$ is linear … and it is clear that $T$ is linear". I hope I am missing something here?

Comment: Well

$$ T(p (a+bx+cx^2+dx^3)) = T((pa)+(pb)x+(pc)x^2+(pd)x^3) = (pa)(pd)x+(pa+pd)x^2+(pb-pc)x^3 = p(a+dx+(a+d)x^2+(b-c)x^3) = p T(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3)
$$

The other is also straight forward...

Comment: I didn't mean to say that it wasn't obvious. I meant to say that the OP asked "How do I show that $T$ is linear" and the relevant part of your answer is *literally* "[definition of $T$] [definition of linearity] and it is clear that $T$ is linear."

Comment: @Eric - it is good that you are critical. My idea was to help by writing what has to be shown (those remaining steps could be done by the other) - I am not going to do homework for others... ;)

Comment: You know what, I've looked through some of your other answers, and I'm pretty impressed. I'll be honest: I was looking for more examples of the implicit holier-than-thou attitude you've shown the OP here, but it seems like this one was an outlier. Therefore, I'm just going to assume you had a rough day yesterday and were on MSE to try to relieve some of that tension and it accidentally came through. I think you should delete this answer, which IMO unfairly besmirches your otherwise good standing. And I know you don't owe anything to me, but it would mean a lot to me if you apologized to the OP